# Can't push a map inside a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

The following code doesn't work, it gives the following errors:

> No matching function for call to object of type 'const comparer'
>
> and
>
> Call to object of type 'value_compare' (aka 'std::_*1::*_map_value_compare, int, comparer, true>') is ambiguous

Here is the code:

```
struct comparer
{
    bool operator()(const std::string x, const std::string y)
    {
        return x.compare(y)<0;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector< map<string,int,comparer> > valMapVect;
    map<string,int,comparer> valMap;

    valMapVect.push_back(valMap);

}
```

It is compiled with Xcode 5.x (so on a Mac).

Somebody has an idea of what is wrong? I think it was working a while ago when I was compiling it on Linux. Is it possible?

Comment: I see no issue with this.

Comment: I think your operator() should be const based on the error message, though I didn't realize that was a requirement here.

Comment: Take a look at std::less<T> implementation. Its operator() is const and accepts arguments by references.

Comment: It compiled fine for me with gnu c++.

you should define your function as:
bool operator()(const std::string& x, const std::string& y) const though

Comment: [No problem here](http://ideone.com/NWzDoV).

Comment: Thanks, adding the const worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) wants the function call operator in `comparer` to be a `const` member function:

```
struct comparer
{
    bool operator()(const std::string x, const std::string y) const
    {                                                      // ^^^^^ fixes the problem
        return x.compare(y)<0;
    }
};
```

Personally I would pass the arguments as `std::string const&` (note the `&`) but that doesn't change whether libc++ likes the comparison object. I'm not, yet, sure if the standard mandates that the `const` is present. I didn't spot such a requirement which would imply that the comparison function would have to be kept as a `mutable` member. However, given that it is often stateless, it is desirable to derive from it to not waste any memory (i.e., take advantage of the empty base optimization) which is probably what libc++ does. It isn't quite clear whether

- it is a bug in libc++, i.e., that the comparison function object has to be stored a `mutable` member.
- in the standard to not mandate the function call operator to be `const`.
- in the code using it to make the function call operator `const`.

The easiest fix is, however, to make function call operator `const`.

Comment: It must be "a binary predicate type" but I can't find the actual definition of that term.

Comment: Thanks @Dietmar Kühl